# "Parse" touch events in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, multi-touch

I've got a demo that is required to run in Firefox on a Windows 7 touch tablet. According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Touch_events), Mozilla has implemented a standardized touch API. However, this does not work on a windows 7 tablet. None of these events are triggered in FF 14.

we have to use the `MozTouchMove` event. But all it does is dispatch sequential events. WI.e. finger one then finger two then finger three etc.

It's difficult to even distinguish two fingers from one. I'd have to measure the distance between updates the assign my own "IDs" to each "Region". After that, to detect a two-finger drag, we'd have to make sure the parsing stays the same throughout--which if one finger goes up may "undrag" as the "second" position is overwritten by the "first" position. Trying to come up with an approach. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
// multitouch event handler for two finger scrolling in x or y
function onTouchMove(event) {

    var eventTouch = new point(event.clientX, event.clientY);

    if (previousTouch.x == 0 && previousTouch.y == 0) {
        previousTouch = new point(eventTouch.x, eventTouch.y);                
        return;
    }


    //filter really close touches
    //in this case, assume single touch and defer to system mouse
    if (previousTouch !== undefined) {
        if (eventTouch.distance(previousTouch) < 6) {
            return;
        }
    }

    fingerIndex ++;

    // only track every other touch to keep fingers consistent
    if( fingerIndex % 2 == 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("finger1").style.left = previousTouch.x + "px";
        document.getElementById("finger1").style.top = previousTouch.y + "px";

        document.getElementById("finger2").style.left = eventTouch.x + "px";
        document.getElementById("finger2").style.top = eventTouch.y + "px";
    }

    previousTouch = eventTouch;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The status document you link to is dated July 2010 - Mozilla *was* close, two years ago. So you are now using the [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Touch_events_%28Mozilla_experimental%29) single-touch API and attempting to implement multi-touch - this is bound to get ugly. The documentation actually points you to the new [multi-touch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Touch_events) that is available since Firefox 12. This lets you distinguish the touches properly and the documentation actually explains in much detail how you would do it.

Comment: I just tried again to double check. None of the events from the "standard" API fire. The deprecated version is all that works. I've disabled extensions like firebug etc. in case they were capturing events. no luck.